# How to change AliExpress' language from Spanish to English?

Tags: localization, aliexpress

AliExpress does not have good customer service which you can easily contact, just robots which work unsuccessfully in this case. Also their help is limited. For some reason, the language of their system changed to Spanish in my account. I do not know Spanish.

How can you change the language of AliExpress to English?

Comment: At least also make English language permanent as the Spanish language is, i think it will be better too that wat

Comment: I found solution for this. Here it is https://www.reddit.com/r/Aliexpress/comments/mip732

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Simply delete your cookies in your browser (I use Chrome).
Specifically, the one for alibaba.com
However, deleting all your cookies is usually a good idea.

Some have suggested: when Aliexpress comes up in Spanish just click the English site button on the top right. However, this is only a temporary fix and doesn't solve the problem long term. 
Just delete the cookie(s).

Comment: My final solution was to use NordVPN to change my geolocation and language. For some reason, there are bugs in the main system such that the server is giving you wrong languages. To change the geolocation for a moment resolved the issue.

Comment: Clicking "Go to Global Site (English)" points you back to aliexpress home and not the product you're viewing.

Comment: removing cookies never helps to switch to normal English interface bro.

Answer (score 15):

This is how to change AliExpress to English.

Usually the problem is that AliExpress detects your country location incorrectly, thus displaying the wrong language -- here are several solutions that you can try (results vary).

**Cookie solution**

1. First clear your browser cookies (for aliexpress.com & alibaba.com).
2. Important; Open the first page in English after clearing cookies.
3. Now AliExpress should remember English as the default language.

[More detailed instructions here (source).](https://www.elftronix.com/changing-aliexpress-language-to-english-the-cookie-method/)

**VPN solution**

The permanent solution is to use a VPN to change your "geolocation" -- so that you can obtain a working IP address from the nearest English speaking country (US, UK, etc).

Not any VPN will do, especially when doing security sensitive shopping activities **(a)** VPN needs to be trusted **(b)** it's better to have many server locations to choose from.

**Other solutions**

This is the most obvious but can fail,  click on the "*Go to Global Site (English)*" link:

[image: AliExpress change to English link]

You can also try to obtain a different IP address by contacting through other means, such as your phone connection, friends house, neighbour, etc.

Comment: "Go to Global Site (English)" is so pain in the ass, as it always tries to switch back.

Comment: It doesn't work, it goes to the main site but when you search a new product it's shown again in the wrong language.

Comment: If for whatever reason that link is unavailable on the page, navigate to some other page (like My Orders for instance). You'll have to figure this on your own if you are stuck with non-english version web page. From there you can find that link...

Comment: Here is solution which worked for me https://www.reddit.com/r/Aliexpress/comments/mf0tvo/fix_cant_change_aliexpress_languagewebsite_to/

Comment: Clearing cookies was enough for me. I guess I got lucky!

Answer (score 8):

Try to edit and lock those cookies:

```
aep_usuc_f  =  region=AU&site=glo&b_locale=en_US&c_tp=USD
intl_locale  =  en_US
xman_us_f  =  x_l=0&x_locale=en_US
```

[Source](https://ask.alibaba.com/Q/5000392010.html)

Comment: I have to add the solution is good, but not complete. When you go from shortened urls, which point on localized item page, like https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/...  , the localization is overriden, and you have to change it manually every time! The solution is Redirector addon, which changes a url on the fly. All you need to do is to add a rule (example for Russian): 1. Include pattern: https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/* 2. Redirect to: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/$1  This changes https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/... to https://www.aliexpress.com/item/... and cookies will be preserved!

Comment: Using Redirector addon seemed a good solution, I tried but Aliexpress does a redirect again to the `ru.` page ending in too many redirects error

Comment: Redirector does not work for me (endless loop), I added all aliexpress.ru to adblock. And the solution that I presented in the answer has not worked for a long time...

Comment: it works properly until you follow the link to store. When I go to store page all cookies reset to unnecessary values even if they were locked for modification.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for Chrome users - [AliEng extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alieng/iheckgdalcgijkcgcdfcpifpphodepnn) which changes the language of AliExpress site to English.

Answer (score 1):

### Bookmark it with the URL query string parameter `lan=en`

```
https://best.aliexpress.com/?lan=en
```

This will work even if you delete all cookies at the end of each session.
You can [**try it out here**](https://best.aliexpress.com/?lan=en).

Answer (score 0):

On the top right corner, there is an option

"Go to Global site (English)".

Just click on it and your problem will be resolved.

[image: You can see this text in this image]

Comment: It doesn't work, it goes to the main site but when you search a new product it's shown again in the wrong language.

Answer (score -1):

Download the app. Just click the red box with  icon, even though it was in Spanish the app installed in English.