# How to change AliExpress product page to English

Tags: aliexpress

That questions is not dupe of [How to Change AliExpress' language from Spanish to English?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/how-to-change-aliexpress-language-from-spanish-to-english)

I wish to change product page to English because AliExpress uses auto translation to my native language and it is not readable at all. I found way to translate page to any language changing 2 letter subdomain domain.

I took first cheapest listing in arduino. ($0.20)

https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Motor-encoder-for-Arduino-Motor-Smart-Robot-Car-Chassis-Kit-Speed-Encoder-Battery-Box-2WD-4WD/32768667682.html?spm=2114.10010208.1000016.1.2NbmVV

if I change `ru` -> `es`

https://es.aliexpress.com/item/Motor-encoder-for-Arduino-Motor-Smart-Robot-Car-Chassis-Kit-Speed-Encoder-Battery-Box-2WD-4WD/32768667682.html?spm=2114.10010208.1000016.1.2NbmVV

Then it changes language to Spanish

If I change `es` -> `www` then I am redirected back to `es`

Also `en` is not working

If I click `Go to Global Site (English)` then I loose listing I was browsing.

- But if I click `Go to Global Site (English)` in New Tab then (I am still on Spanish/Russian)
- then I **Reload** and I get international site.
- next I return to Tab 1 and replace `ru` (`es` or ....)  with `www` then I can open original page.

---

If I add to URL `&isOrigTitle=true` then I get original title.
In past there was option to see original listing but that link is missing now. May be you know what must be added to url e.g. (`&isOrigDescription=true` `&isOrigDesc=true` do not work)

Is there simpler way to disable translations?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this.

1. Clear cookies in your browser for all aliexpress domains
2. Visit the page [report.aliexpress.com](https://report.aliexpress.com) before visiting any other aliexpress pages
3. Click on Aliexpress logo (visit [aliexpress.com](https://aliexpress.com))
4. It is fixed now, stay on English or change to another language via website interface

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Aliexpress/comments/mip732

Answer (score -2):

by clearing all cookies in your browser then go to the official site www.aliexpress.com